# How can I make center moving stacked chart?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, charts

I am trying to make a 100% stacked bar that the center point is dynamically moving left or right according to the ratio getting from some data.
[looks like that..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f3Ja.gif)

I searched chart.js or similar, but their stacked chart resizing from the beginning, not center.
How can I make it with JavaScript, or could you give me any keywords to search?

Comment: How many bars will be displayed? Are these bars resizable by click and dragging? Where does the data come from for this ratio?

Comment: Only one bar with two data. So it will be like ball possession ratio bar in soccer game. Like every 1 min it will get the data from server, and the data will be passed to the chart. And the chart will be resized dynamically according to this data.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with css and javascript. Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jordanmbush/pen/NEremG). The function currently takes in a ratio. 0.3 equals 30%, etc. You just need to pass in 1, and the second bar can be calculated by the remainder, so 70% remaining. Right now, I have `.3` hard coded into the button onClick call, but you  you would basically call this when your data fetch is complete, and pass in your data.

Here is the function:

```js
updateWidth = (ratio) => {
  const bar1 = document.getElementById('bar1');
  const bar2 = document.getElementById('bar2');
  bar1.style.width = `${ratio * 100}%`;
  bar2.style.width = `${(1 - ratio) * 100}%`;
}
```